# The functional equation $f(x+x) = f(x)f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-equations

Consider the exponential functional equation on the diagonal
\begin{align}
f(x+x) = f(x)f(x)\,, \quad f(0) = 1\,.
\end{align}

What are the solutions for this problem? Either for all $x $ or for non-negative $x $.

**EDIT:** Apparently the following is wrong:  I guess the exponential functions $x \mapsto e^{cx}$ are the only solutions if we assume measurability, continuity or some other regularity property.

Comment: And do you mean $f(0)=1$?

Comment: Your proposed solution does not satisfy $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I meant f (0)=1.

Comment: Note that : $f(nx)=f(x)^n $ and $ f(x)f(-x)=1 $

Comment: The above property is sufficient to claim ( correct me if I'm wrong ) that x must be in the exponent , isn't it?

Comment: Let $f(x) = 2^{x2^{g(\log_2 x)}}$ where $g$ is any continuous function with period $1$.

Comment: I suspect that requiring $f$ to be *analytic* might be sufficient to ensure that the exponentials are the only solutions (see my comments below).  But that's a pretty strong assumption.

Comment: @Avi do those claims necessarily follow?

Comment: @Avi:  I'm not sure how you get the second of your claims, and in fact it's violated by one of the counterexamples below.

Comment: I was talking about the first functional equation. $f(x +(-x))=f(x)f(-x)$

Comment: @Avi: I don't think you can substitute $-x$ for one of the $x$'s in the original functional equation but not the other.  That'd be a different condition (though perhaps another interesting one.)

Comment: Yes, I see your point! I take back my second claim. Thanks for correcting me:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Summary:** *There is an uncountably infinite family of $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions on $(0, +\infty)$ satisfying this equation, and these functions are also continuous at $x = 0$ if we demand $f(0) = 1$.  If we further demand that the function be differentiable at $x = 0$, $f(x)$ must be an exponential:  $f(x) = e^{cx}$ for some constant $c$.*

---

Let $g(x): [1,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function satisfying $g(2) = 2g(1)$.  Define a function $h(x): [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ recursively:
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) & 1 < x \leq 2 \\ \frac{1}{2} h(2x) & 0 < x \leq 1 \\ 2 h(x/2)  & x > 2 \\ 0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
For example, by this definition 
$$
h(3) = 2 h(3/2) = 2 g(3/2)
$$
and 
$$
h(3/16) = \frac{1}{2} h(3/8) = \frac{1}{4} h(3/4) = \frac{1}{8} h(3/2) = \frac{1}{8} g(3/2).
$$
The graph of this function would be self-similar:
[image]

By construction, $h(2x) = 2 h(x)$ for all $x$.  But we can then define $f(x) = e^{h(x)}$;  and therefore $f(2x) = e^{h(2x)} = e^{2 h(x)} = (e^{h(x)})^2 = f(x)^2$.  Moreover, we have 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0_+} h(x) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \lim_{x \to 0_+} f(x) = 1
$$
and so the function is continuous at $x = 0$.

If you want the function to satisfy any particular derivative conditions, you can also demand that $g^{(n)}(1) = 2^{n-1} g^{(n)}(2)$ for any and all values of $n$ you desire.  In particular, you can choose $g$ to be a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function for which all of the derivatives match at $x = 1$ and $x = 2$, and $f(x)$ will be a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function as well.

The exponential family of functions you found correspond to choosing $g(x)$ to be a linear function on $[1,2]$.  A similar construction can be made to extend $h(x)$ (and thereby $f(x)$) to the negative real numbers as well;  the $g(x)$ we choose to construct $f(x)$ on this domain need not be the same function as the one we used for the positive reals.  [@mfl's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1943559/248639) corresponds to taking $g(x) = x$ for the positive reals and $g(x) = -x$ for the negative reals.

---

**EDIT:** After further thought, I'm convinced that even if $g(x)$ is a $\mathcal{C}^n$ function on its domain, the resulting function $h(x)$ will not be $\mathcal{C}^n$ at $x = 0$ unless $n = 0$.  This can be seen by noting that we have
$$
h^{(n)}(x) = \begin{cases} g^{(n)}(x) & 1 < x \leq 2 \\ 2^{n-1} h^{(n)}(2x) & 0 < x \leq 1 \\ 2^{1-n} h^{(n)}(x/2)  & x > 2 \\ 0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
For $n > 1$, consider the sequence of values $x_m = a/2^m$, with $1<a<2$. It can be seen that $h^{(n)}(x_m) = 2^{m(n-1)} g^{(n)}(a)$.   This sequence of values will diverge as $x_m \to 0$, and so the $n$th derivative of $h$ cannot approach a finite value as $x \to 0$.  The only exception here is if $g^{(n)}(a) = 0$ for all $a$, i.e., $g(x)$ is a linear function.  In this case, the resulting $f(x)$ is an exponential.

For $n = 1$, meanwhile, $h'(x)$ will take on all possible values of $g'(x)$ in every interval containing the origin;  and so $h'(x)$ cannot have a well-behaved limit as $x \to 0$ either.  The only exception here is if $g'(x)$ is a constant over its domain, in which case we get $f(x)$ as an exponential function as well.

Comment: I believe that the function proposed by @Rahul in the comments on the original question is equivalent to this method, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 21):

Your claim is false. For example

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} e^x & x\ge 0 \\ e^{-x} & x<0 \end{cases}$$

satisfies the functional equation, is continuous and is not an exponential function.

Answer (score 2):

Be $f(x):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ and $a_0:=1$.

With $f(2x)=f(x)^2$ follows $\sum\limits_{v=0}^k a_v a_{k-v}=2^k a_k$.

This means, that $a_1$ can be *any* value.

We get the exponential function $e^{a_1 x}$. $\enspace$(as $\pi r8$ and *Michael Seifert* have mentioned below)

*Short hint*: $\enspace\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \frac{(a_1)^v}{v!} \frac{(a_1)^{k-v}}{(k-v)!}=a_1^k\frac{(1+1)^k}{k!}=2^k \frac{(a_1)^k}{k!}$

This shows that functions which can be represented by Taylor series, can only be exponentially, if they solve the claim above.

Comment: Right, but that wouldn't necessarily be incompatible with OP's statement - $e^{a_1x}$ is in the family of solutions proposed.

Comment: @πr8:  Moreover, if you go through the first few values of $k$ above, you find that $a_2 = a_1^2/2$, $a_3 = a_1^3/6$, and $a_4 = a_1^4/24$.  I suspect that continuing this will just yield the power series for $e^{a_1 x}$.  This might then serve as a proof that requiring $f(x)$ to be analytic at $x = 0$ (as opposed to just $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$) implies that it is an exponential function.

Comment: @Michael Seifert : Yes thanks, right. I will delete this post soon.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily delete it, actually.  I suspect it shows that if a power series about $x = 0$ exists (i.e., the function is analytic there), then it must be an exponential.  Ideally, one would want to prove this rigorously by showing that $a_n = a_1^n/n!$ for all $n$ (not just the few that I calculated.)

Comment: @Michael Seifert : Thank you, I have corrected. :-)